# Build trigger don't get saved in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean, build-triggers

We have a nighly build that triggers build of many different projects to verify external testing like contracts and such to avoid triggering such tests on every checkin.

However lately we have encountered a problem, if you open a build configuration and enter any parameter or build triggers and then saves the configuration. Once you save it gives no indication as to an error or anything but if you open it again its not there, no build trigger or parameter gets saved.

We have managed to isolate it to pipeline build, freestyle builds still works.

We installed Blue Ocean recently and are not wondering if it somehow changes how a pipeline job definition is saved. It seems a bad decision if Blue ocean hinders such a basic setting but still. We haven't been able to create a pipeline job throught blue ocean either since our job isn't triggered by any SCM and blue ocean requires that.

Comment: I have same issue with `Jenkins 2.277.2`, when edit job and save. its not storing the values.